# Divide by Zero workaround

Tags: r

I am calculating passes per shot for a number of games and summarizing by team. There are a few games where zero shots were taken. For this analysis I feel it is more important to replace the 0 with a 1, rather than omit the game. How would I do that in R? Here is my code.

```
match_df <- data.frame(TeamName = c("Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team B", "Team B", "Team B"), Passes = c(325,300,350,250,275,300), Shots = c(10,8,12,5,5,0))

overview <- match_df %>% 
  mutate(PassesPerShot = Passes / Shots) %>% 
  select(TeamName, PassesPerShot) %>% 
  group_by(TeamName) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~round(mean(.),digits = 1))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(PassesPerShot))
```

Comment: it's a reasonable decision, but I would think **very** carefully about whether you really want to do this. Suppose you have some sequence of games where you had 5 passes/5 shots, 4 passes/4 shots, 3 passes/3 shots ... is zero the end of this sequence?  Maybe go to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), give more context about your analysis, and ask for advice?

Comment: Thanks. I've gone back and forth whether to drop it or modify - at least now I can play with both and see the effects. And thanks for the link - looks very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `replace` by 1

```
library(dplyr)
match_df %>% 
     mutate(PassesPerShot = Passes / replace(Shots, Shots == 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if a workaround with `pmax` makes sense for your case

```
within(match_df,PassesPerShot <- Passes/pmax(Shots,1))
```

such that

```
> within(match_df,PassesPerShot <- Passes/pmax(Shots,1))
  TeamName Passes Shots PassesPerShot
1   Team A    325    10      32.50000
2   Team A    300     8      37.50000
3   Team A    350    12      29.16667
4   Team B    250     5      50.00000
5   Team B    275     5      55.00000
6   Team B    300     0     300.00000
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not familiar with pmax and will take a look at it.